# addAttributeToFilter() - does second argument need to be escaped?

Tags: database, collection, security

Does a second argument in

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('col3', $second_argument)
```

need to be escaped or not(Magento escapes it/uses parametrized queries) when it's provided by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not need to.

In Magento 1, `addAttributeToFilter` ends up calling `_where` in `lib/Zend/Db/Select.php` which does the following:

```
$condition = $this->_adapter->quoteInto($condition, $value, $type);
```

In Magento 2, I reckon it's the `_where` method in `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php` but this is the same file just a different location.

The `quoteInto` method takes care of the escaping ;)